# Game engine vs graphic engine vs rendering engine

Tags: render, graphic

What is the difference between game engine, graphic engine and rendering engine?

A game engine is a software framework for the development of video games. Can we use game engine for creating graphics, CGI, or must use graphic engine for this process.

e.g cryengine, unreal engine 4 is used for development games or we can use this engines for designed 3 dimensions images?

And rendering engine is the part of game engine or it is something special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two types of render engines. One type is called graphic engine which calculates images from data you put in and helps you to draw it. The other type are engines like a rendering engine of HTML. These engines draw element which are defined in HTML. A game engine is a bundle of different functions you need to build a game. For example they contain graphic-engines, physic-engines, sound-engines and so on.

Engines like Unreal-Engine 4 or CryEngine are very huge game-engines. You can do alot of stuff with them. To answer your questions: Yes with UE4 and CryEngine you can create graphics and CGI.

It would be helpful if you could say to us what you want to render. Maybe it would make more sense to use something else.

BR!